# Checking QMimeData in QDragEnterEvent and QDropEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering if it's good practice to check the QMimeData on both the drag enter and drop event? It seems like in this case it's necessary in order to set the accept/ignore events of each scenario. I just wanted to make sure I was not doing something that was bad practice.

```
#include "lineeditpath.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QMimeData>


LineEditPath::LineEditPath(QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void LineEditPath::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    if (mimeData->hasUrls() && mimeData->urls().count()==1) {
        event->accept();
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void LineEditPath::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    if (mimeData->hasUrls()) {
        setText(mimeData->urls().first().toLocalFile());
    }
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: It is a good practice since with them you can filter the different types of data

Comment: @eyllanesc As far as I know a widget cannot receive a drop event if it ignored the drag enter event? Thus in this case checking the mime data again in the drop event handler seems unnecessary.

Comment: @corristo I'll try that out. That's a good point